# Using AWS budgets to stop a services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently signed up to the free tier of AWS. I am enjoying experimenting with various services including those not affording by said free tier. Can AWS's enhanced budgets be used to stop services like EC2 instances if I accidentally spend too much? Or do they merely act as alerts?

Answer (score 8):

This is available for EC2, I don't think it is available for all of the AWS resources.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

There are several posts which looks it from different perspectives, such as [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183735/how-to-prevent-cost-attacks-on-aws) and [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Amazon-provide-any-tools-to-cap-AWS-usage-costs).

Having a cost cap might be a crucial requirement based on the usage, especially when considering how complex it is to set the things up properly and keeping everything secure on the cloud for an average user. At least we can expect to have a feature to switch on/off a cost-cap service, so a user can decide their own scenario easily.

Closest solution that I found is here:

- Serverless Automated Cost Controls
  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/serverless-automated-cost-controls-part1

It explains how to trigger AWS Lambda function to change IAM permission from `EC2FullAccess` to `EC2ReadOnly` when the budget exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 5):

Recently, Amazon has given "budget action" to carry out actions like stop services automatically if the budget has exceeded.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/announcing-aws-budgets-actions/

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-controls.html#:~:text=select%20Configure%20thresholds.-,To%20configure%20a%20budget%20action,-Under%20Configure%20thresholds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-controls.html#:%7E:text=select%20Configure%20thresholds.-,To%20configure%20a%20budget%20action,-Under%20Configure%20thresholds)

Answer (score 4):

<strike>There is no built-in way to terminate services based on budgets or billing alarms.</strike>

You can get notified automatically, but it is then up to you to determine how to handle it.

Would you really want AWS automatically terminating your production infrastructure because you went $1 over your estimated monthly spending?

Edit:  There is now a way to monitor and alert on free tier usage, and when your predicted usage will exceed the free tier.  See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html) for details.  You could probably come up with a way to terminate infrastructure based on an alert using SNS & lambda.

Edit 2:  In Oct. 2020, AWS released Budget Actions - the ability to trigger an action when a budget thresholds are reached.  This should give you the ability to automate a response - you can shut down servers, change IAM permissions to prevent additional infrastructure from being created, etc.

Comment: OP's questions clearly says, he is enjoying experimenting, not making money with it or need to be highly available.

Comment: Right, but AWS has no way of knowing what type of load you are running.   You can always wire up events to lambda to do whatever you want, but that is not functionality that AWS offers.

Comment: It just started with EC2, you can Terminate EC2 instance with an alarm. More resources will get added. It should be scalable not just with technology but with also money as well. When I can't pay enough it should have the capability to shut it down, not with code.

Comment: Assuming I am fooling around with AWS and didn't secure my service well enough, I am dreading what could be going on over night.

Comment: @Dan - IF you were to leak your credentials, you could very shortly see services running up charges at a $5000/hr - $10000/hr  rate.

Comment: @chris > $charges at a $5000/hr - $10000/hr rate < *removes root access keys* *enables 2fa* :P

Comment: say one has an s3 bucket that is public ,can you change it to make it private if a particular amount is reached. I have not read it fully yet, but I believe can be done, https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=aws+budget+actions anybody able to confirm please ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could read, there is no way to set a hard limit.

What I did was set up the recommended budget notification and I'm also using a prepaid VISA card as a default payment method, so that I can be sure not to spend more than what I have on this card.

I think that's the safest option.

Comment: I am not an expert, but would using a prepaid card really get you off the hook if they bill you? I can see the payment may be denied, but it feels like you would still have to pay all the bills eventually.