# How can I rate limit AWS S3 bucket access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket which holds a generated sitemap file, which needs to be publicly accessible. I'm afraid if someone finds out about the url and DDOSes it, it could cost me a fortune. Is there a way to rate limit the requests per second accessing a S3 bucket?

Comment: You can put a CloudFront distribution in front of your S3 bucket and make the bucket private. CloudFront contains automatic DDos protection.You can also use AWS Shield in front of your S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've just read up about AWS Shield - isn't it enabled per default?

Comment: I didn't explain it well. "You can also use AWS Shield in front of your cloudfront" is a better explanation. You can use CloudFront in front of your S3 (it contains default DDoS protection (AWS Shield Standard) just like Route53). If you want more advanced protection you can enable AWS Shield Advanced above your CloudFront but this is quite expensive I remember.

Comment: cloud be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnoZS5jj7pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for Content Delivery Network (CDN). With a CDN that specializes in DDOS e.g. you can setup a webservice to feed the S3 files and cache based on querystring

2) You can use API Gateway infront of your S3 Request to limit number of request. But i am afraid, incase of any DDOS attack, you will lock down the real users from making request

3) using CDN with WAF (Web Application Firewall) where you can define rules to safeguard from DDoS attacks. I am afraid if it will work directly with S3, but using a combination of Cloud Front or Cloud Watch logs you can implement this.

[Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is your personal AWS and you have access to the billing alerts and budgets, you can set up an alarm to notify at a threshold and stop at a threshold for a particular service like S3

[Using AWS budgets to stop a services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773818/using-aws-budgets-to-stop-a-services)